# How to get the class name which is calling another class static funcaion

Tags: c#, oop

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Retrieving the calling method name from within a method (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method-c)

I have a class say `A` in which there is a Method called `Func1`; this function is static.
Now there are some other classes say `B`, `C` that use `A.Func1`

How can I get the class name which contains the function that is calling ?

ie

```
public class A  
{  
    public static void Func1()  
    {  
    // who called me?  
    }  
}  

public class B  
{  
    public void CallFunc()  
    {  
        A.Func1();  
    }  
}

public class C
{  
    public void AlsoCallFunc()  
    {  
        A.Func1();  
    }  
}
```

Comment: Clarify the question, Post some code, Help us to help you..

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method-c - however, I strongly suggest you remove the need for this; such techniques are brittle **at best**. Virtually any other design would be preferable.

Comment: Actually, my senario is, in my class there is an event, in this event there are some calculation based on the calling winform thats why i need of this.

Comment: Marc is right - this is one of the smelliest code-smells you'll ever find.  Don't do it.

Comment: If you have an event handler its first parameter is the sender. Maybe you can use that sender to get the calling form.

Comment: Rather than identifying the caller by stack trace, why not inject the additional informations required as a method parameter? If its a genuine event then you can use the sender or have custom event args with additional information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need to work with form and want to know which form is calling then use event and sender

Answer (score 2):

Can use [StackTrace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) class in order to acees that kind of information.

To get calling method name, I sometimes use this function. *But you need to check if it works in your specific case*:

```
private static string GetCallingMethodName()
{        
    const int iCallDeepness = 2; 
    System.Diagnostics.StackTrace stack = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace(false);
    System.Diagnostics.StackFrame sframe = stack.GetFrame(iCallDeepness);
    return sframe.GetMethod().Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you work with the output of

```
Environment.StackTrace
```