# Get calling method's Namespace and Assembly

Tags: c#, .net

Is there a trick in `System.Reflection` to get the Namespace of a method that is calling another method? What I currently have is:

```
var stackTrace = new System.Diagnostics.StackTrace();
MethodBase method = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
string namespace = method.DeclaringType.Namespace;
Assembly assembly = method.DeclaringType.Assembly;
```

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method-c

Comment: Watch out for optimization in the Release configuration, it can change the call stack.

Comment: You can use the [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImpl(
 System.Runtime.CompilerServices.MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)] so in release it won't inline the method

Answer (score 0):

No, and even your trick will NOT WORK in production if the calling method is inlined - i.e. so small that the compiler makes it in line to the next one.

There is no reliable way to get this infomration.

http://www.mehdi-khalili.com/that-tricky-stacktrace