# Grabbing the function and filename in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

Is there a way to grab the function name and file name when I'm inside a function?  I'm trying to add log files all over the place like so, and want to be able to just copy and paster my logfile line of code in certain functions:

```
public class NewCorrGenerator
{
    public void Start()
    {
        bool rc = true;

        myLogFile.InfoToFileWithTime("NewCorrGenerator - Start", appContext);

        etc.....
    }
}
```

As you can see is there a way to grab the class name and function name in a string and output it to myLogFile function?

Comment: I would love to see if there is a new way to accomplish this with .net 4.5

Comment: @MennanKara have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [GetCurrentMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.getcurrentmethod%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  This will return an object of type `MethodBase`.  The `Name` property to get the name of the method.  `DeclaringType` will give you the class.  This isn't the same as the file name, but it should be close if you use one type per file.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`System.Diagnostics.StackTrace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stacktrace.aspx) and [`System.Diagnostics.StackFrame`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stackframe.aspx) classes to retrieve information about the currently executing code:

```
var trace = new StackTrace(true);
var frame = trace.GetFrame(0);  // current frame
var lineNumber = frame.GetFileLineNumber();
var method = frame.GetMethod().Name;
var className = frame.GetMethod().ReflectedType.Name;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but the need is still relevant. So for the record, easy way with new tools -- [CallerMemberName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute?view=net-7.0) and [CallerFilePath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerfilepathattribute?view=net-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

What you need is called an Interceptor. The most popular framework for this is [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/). Its a commercial product that would do everything you need. If you want to write your own, try looking at [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD)

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection to get what you need.  Here is a way to get the method name: [Retrieving the calling method name from within a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method-c)

I would consider doing something else though - either interception or code generation that hardcodes class/method names in.  If you do end up using StackTrace it may be a good idea to surround the logging code with compiler debug directives.