# Automatically log all parameters that were passed to some method

Tags: c#, log4net

Let's say I have some function that accepts two integers. Is it a way to automatically log a message like this
`"[Date][MethodNam]([first param],[second param]) - "`

What have I tried so far - specify the following layout pattern:

```
<conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] [%C.%M] – %message%newline" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an IoC framework such as Windsor you can use AOP (Aspect-oriented programming) to inject a wrapper round your interfaces. You can then log the method call. Here is an example using Windsor and the IInteceptor interface, this is a striped down version of what we use but there are various examples available.

```
public class LoggingInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        Type targetType = invocation.TargetType ?? invocation.Method.DeclaringType;

        ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(targetType);

        //Probably want to check logger.IsDebugEnabled

        if(invocation.Arguments.Count() == 0)
        {
            logger.DebugFormat("Method '{0}' called.", invocation.Method);
        }
        else
        {
            var stringBuilder = new StringBuilder("{" + invocation.Arguments.Length + "}");

            for (int i = invocation.Arguments.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                stringBuilder.Insert( 0, "{" + i + "}, " );
            }

            logger.DebugFormat("Method '{0}' called with parameters: " + stringBuilder, new[] { invocation.Method }.Union(invocation.Arguments).ToArray());
        }

        try
        {
            invocation.Proceed();

            if (invocation.Method.ReturnType != typeof(void))
            {
                logger.DebugFormat("Method '{0}' returned: {1}", invocation.Method, invocation.ReturnValue);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            logger.Error(string.Format("Method '{0}' threw exception:", invocation.Method), ex);
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your IoC framework you should be able wire up individual components.

POINT TO NOTE:

This will work for interfaces methods only, it will not wire up the private methods on an object.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what is log4net, but you can use reflection to obtain runtime data or debug features and then save it, read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method-c).

Answer (score 0):

What you need i called `Aspect Oriented Programming` (AOP) [Here](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/aspect-oriented-frameworks) is a list of AOP frameworks. Don't know if any allows you to insert logging of arguments but [Loom.net](http://loom.codeplex.com/documentation) looks promising.