# How to identfiy Class or Method Name into method in C#?

Tags: c#, class, methods

I don't know it is possible or not, but if there is some way to do this then please suggest.
I have one method and I am call this method with different classes, so how will I able to 
know(Class Name) into method, that from which method is called?

Below is my scenario,

```
public class Employee()
{
    protected bool Check()
    {
         //Here how will I know method name(Test1 or Test2) from which call is made? Please note I can't use any parameter with Check method.
    }
    public void Test1()
    {
         Check();
    }
    public void Test2()
    {
         Check();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suspect this is a consequence of poor design.

Comment: You need to fix your example so it compiles.

Comment: This smells like an XY problem. Can you provide more context what you are trying to do and why?

Comment: I have one class Employee and one common method Check is called in every rest of methods. Now I want to know method name in common method(Check) from which methods(Test1 or Test2) call is made.

Comment: Refer this; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `StackTrace`;

```
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
MethodBase methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();
Console.WriteLine(methodBase.Name);
```

Thanks to [Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/615940/retrieving-the-calling-method-name-from-within-a-method)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
string myClass = MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
```

And in C# 6.0 then you can use [nameof](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/552376)

```
nameof(YourMethodname)
```

Comment: It gives me Employee instead of Test1 or Test2.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
var className = this.GetType().Name;
```

Comment: I got Employee Instead of Test1 or Test2

Comment: Because Check() is a member of the Employee class.Your original question asked for class name.

Answer (score -1):

You will find your answer 
[here](http://www.csharp-examples.net/reflection-calling-method-name)

```
using System.Diagnostics;

// get call stack
StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();

// get calling method name
Console.WriteLine(stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name);
```